# .toFixed with 3 digit but last digit should be zero

Tags: javascript

can i get 3 digit after decimal with 3rd digit as zero
for example

```
var x = 5.123456;
y = x.toFixed(3);
```

in this value in y will be `5.123` but the result should be as **5.120**

Comment: Try toFixed(2) and append a 0 maybe?

Comment: Why marked as 'jquery'?

Comment: Thanks Tim Hallyburton. your trick worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
var x = 5.123456;
y = x.toFixed(2);
z = Number(y).toFixed(3);

console.log(z);
```